# Does leaving thanks type comments get automatically/mod deleted at some point or should I be deleting them myself after?

Tags: discussion

Do I need to try to pay attention to comments like thanks with a sentence or something afterward.

Sorry for a stupid-ish question, but I'm very new with regards to social media sites.

Comment: I don't consider StackExchange Q&A sites to be "social media."

Comment: @JYelton sadly I do, I've always been against getting involved in most any website. However, SE is so cool and not spammy, etc. that it makes it worth my effort to contribute! I just need to get the hang of being social, online. Like my reply to [your comment](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/53310/9730), I had no clue you were hinting, etc.

Comment: I'll admit it's "social" in the aspect of interacting with other people. That interaction, however, is based on knowledge, experience, and technical information. When someone refers to "social media" or "social networking" it usually means things like Facebook, Twitter, etc. which are more focused on personal information, relationships, family, and general fluff.

Comment: Link to related meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/134987

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are wanting to thank someone just up vote. Comments such as, "Thanks for the help." are just noise. If it is helpful, up vote. If it solves your problem, accept. If you need further information or have input to give them about the situation please post a comment explaining.

Although I am sure someone will say that saying thanks is appreciated, that is a duplicate of up voting with less lasting value. It is the same as signing a signature, don't do it because the site puts a little signature on your post for you.